# Does sass support to use parent selector as follows?

Tags: css, sass, selector

## Problem

I mainly use the following methods. (SASS)

```
.person {
    &.man {
        .head { A }
    }

    &.woman {
        .head { B }
    }

    .head { C }
}
```

But I want to use the following method. (SASS)

```
.person {
    .head {
        C

        <parent_selector.man> {
            A
        }

        <parent_selector.woman> {
            B
        }
    }
}
```

compiled result (CSS)

```
.person .head { C }
.person.man .head { A }
.person.woman .head { B }
```

I want to know if there is such a function. Thank you.

## My result

I got the idea from @falsarella's @at-root approach. It seems a bit crude, but this is also possible. (I actually used deeper selectors than the example, so it was hard to solve with at-root and #{$} alone.)

```
.person {
    $person: &;

    .head {
        C

        @at-root #{$person}.man .head {
            A
        }

        @at-root #{$person}.woman .head {
            B
        }
    }
}
```

Or it would be more convenient and readable(If the parent selector is not a simple selector.) to use it by naming $parent and overriding the previous $parent.

When I think about it once, the current selector is named $parent, so it is confusing. It might be better to ignore '>', ':after', ... of a parent selector and just name it as $person. (or create naming conventions.)

```
.earth {
    $parent: &;

    .person {
        $parent: &;

        .head {
            C

            @at-root #{$parent}.man .head {
                A
            }

            @at-root #{$parent}.woman .head {
                B
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result of further Googling, postcss seems to support parent selectors I want.

Comment: No: SASS ultimately compiles to CSS, which [does not have a parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1324).

Comment: @Paul Roub Thank you, but it seems that what I said is not well communicated. The parent selector in sass, not the parent selector in css. I added the compiled result.

Comment: Your question was clear, and the answer is the same. SASS lets you write CSS at a higher level, but it does not give you magical selector powers that CSS lacks.

Comment: @Paul Roub Okay, I got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "parent" selector in Sass, but, in your case, you can use a tricky `#{&}` interpolation together with `@at-root`, like this:

```
.person {
    .head {
        color: white;

        @at-root .man#{&} {
            color: blue;
        }

        @at-root .woman#{&} {
            color: pink;
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting in the following CSS:

```
.person .head {
  color: white;
}
.man.person .head {
  color: blue;
}
.woman.person .head {
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: The https://www.sassmeister.com/ sandbox compiles it to a bit different result, i.e.: `.person .head .man.person .head {`.

Comment: @GlebKost I've updated my answer with a working example. Nice point. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, not. I think the first example that you give is the best way to achieve this. Another option might be:

```
  .head {
    .person & {
      color: red;
    }
    .person.man & {
      color: blue;
    }
    .person.woman & {
      color: green;
    }
  }
```

It will produce the same compiled result as you desire. But beware of nesting the `.head` class. It will trip you up.

Comment: Thank you! I also like the way. It would be best if I could wrap it as a parent selector.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not really uses a parent selector. Just uses a SASS `@mixin` to give same CSS output.

```
@mixin personHead($gender) {
    @if $gender == man {
        &.man .head{
            property: A; 
        }
    }
    @if $gender == woman {
        &.woman .head{
            property: B; 
        }
    }
    @if $gender == "" {
        .head{
            property: C; 
        }
    }
}

.person { @include personHead(man); }
.person { @include personHead(woman); }
.person { @include personHead(""); }


/* Compiled CSS Output */

.person.man .head {
    property: A;
}

.person.woman .head {
    property: B;
}

.person .head {
    property: C;
}
```